# Handling orientation change in custom SplitViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have written a custom `SplitViewController` which has a master (custom `UITableView`) and a detail view controller and this works perfectly in the landscape mode of the iPad.

I want to resize and position the master and detail view accordingly when the orientation changes to the portrait mode so that things do not look out of place.

Anyone have any idea on how I can get this done?

UPDATE :

I wrote a listener in my custom SplitViewController to look out for orientation change and hooked that up to a selector (resetViews:) which looks something like this

-(void)resetViews{

```
 if(currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || currentOrientation ==       UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
    masterView.frame = CGRectMake(MASTER_VIEW_PORTRAIT_X,MASTER_VIEW_PORTRAIT_Y,MASTER_VIEW_WIDTH_PORTRAIT,MASTER_VIEW_HEIGHT_PORTAIT);
    detailView.frame = CGRectMake(DETAIL_VIEW_PORTRAIT_X, DETAIL_VIEW_PORTRAIT_Y, DETAIL_VIEW_WIDTH_PORTRAIT, DETAIL_VIEW_HEIGHT_PORTAIT);



}
if(currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight || currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
    NSLog(@"IN Landscape");
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
   masterView.frame = CGRectMake(MASTER_VIEW_LANDSCAPE_X,MASTER_VIEW_LANDSCAPE_Y,MASTER_VIEW_WIDTH_LANDSCAPE,MASTER_VIEW_HEIGHT_LANDSCAPE);
    detailView.frame = CGRectMake(DETAIL_VIEW_LANDSCAPE_X,DETAIL_VIEW_LANDSCAPE_Y, DETAIL_VIEW_WIDTH_LANDSCAPE, DETAIL_VIEW_HEIGHT_LANDSCAPE);


}
```

}

This works fine while setting the frames of the viewControllers.

But the MasterViewController (UITableViewController) has to dynamically change the height of its rows (tableView.rowHeight) when the orientation changes. How do i do this without the need for reloading the entire tableView ([tableView reloadData]) for every orientation change?

Comment: Do you want to get the same behaviour as the stock UISplitViewController, where the master view totally disappear in portrait orientation, or something like the Settings application where the master view remains on screen, thus narrowing the detail view?

Comment: When the orientation changes (say from landscape to portrait)i want the master view to narrow down in width and expand in height (the rowHeight of the table cells should adjust accordingly). The detail view should be resized as well.
These changes should revert back when the orientation is changed back to landscape!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the autoresizingMasks to specify the desired resizing behavior of your views ? Something like this should match the resizing you described :

```
splitViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight;
masterViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight;
detailViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I did try it out, but doesnt work as i need it to, when i did try to set the autoResizingMask property, the entire tableView goes out of the view of the iPad in portrait mode!

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UISplitViewController and set your splitViewController to that class. Then add this method to your UISplitViewController subclass:

```
-(BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return NO;
}
```

If you want an easy way to swap out the detail view add this method:

```
-(void)setDetailControllerTo:(UIViewController *)detailController withNavControllerTitle:(NSString *)title {
[detailController view]; // this line forces the viewDidLoad method to be called

if (title) {
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [navController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
    detailController.title = title;

    NSArray *viewControllers=@[self.mainController.viewControllers[0],navController];
    self.mainController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
} else {
    NSArray *viewControllers=@[self.mainController.viewControllers[0],detailController];
    self.mainController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
}
```

}

To call this method do something like this from the master view controller in the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method

```
FixedSplitViewController *splitController = (FixedSplitViewController*) self.splitViewController;

CurrentEventViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CurrentEventViewController"];
// add any setup code here
[splitController setDetailControllerTo:controller withNavControllerTitle:@"Current Event"];
```